# Laravel PHPUnit Test Throwing Forbidden Error

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5.6

I have written two PHPUnit test that updates and deletes a book record only if the user is authenticated. I am using Passport for authentication but my test fails with a `403` error for both test. What could be wrong with my code below

```
public function test_onlyAuthenticatedUserCanUpdateBookSuccessfully()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();
    Passport::actingAs($user);

    $book = factory(Book::class)->create();

    $response = $this->json('PUT', '/api/books/'.$book->id, [
            'id'    => $book->id,
            'title' => 'Updated book title',
            'author'=> 'New Guy'
        ]);

    $response->assertStatus(201);
}

public function test_onlyAuthenticatedUserCanDeleteBook()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();
    Passport::actingAs($user);

    $book = factory(Book::class)->create();

    $response = $this->json('DELETE', '/api/books/'.$book->id);

    $response->assertStatus(204);
}
```

Here's api.php file in the routes folder

```
Route::apiResource('books', 'BookController');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change the formRequest authorize

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).